# .Htaccess URL Rewriting - Clean URLs not working

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite URLs, but I am getting stuck.

New URL: http://example.com/restaurants/restaurent name

Original URL: http://example.com/restaurants-menu.php?rest=restaurent+name

**CODE I TRIED** (not working)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^rest/([^/]*)\$ /restaurants-menu.php?rest=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working. What do you expect to happen? [How to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @buczek, when users open `http://example.com/restaurants/restaurent name` i want to show them content from `http://example.com/restaurants-menu.php?rest=restaurent name`

Comment: Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: Your regex is wrong. Try: `RewriteRule ^restaurants/([^/]+)/?$ restaurants-menu.php?rest=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: @anubhava, that worked like a charm :D post it as answer bro! will select it and will UPVOTE it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually problem in your regex pattern that matches `rest/` and then literal `$`.

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^restaurants/([^/]+)/?$ restaurants-menu.php?rest=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```